# How to make content respect parent size. Vue3/Vuetify

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I have a container in my app that holds an image, some buttons and loading bar. But it keeps overflowing slightly, while I want it to respect its parent's size and not be larger than the size of the entire screen.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEQhC.jpg)

I'm currently using the vuetify class fill-height to make everything fit the entire screen.

code:

container component

```
<template>
  <v-container class="screen-container fill-height">
    <v-row class="screen-row fill-height">
      <v-col>
        <InputBar />
      </v-col>
      <v-col>
        <ResultScreen />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

ResultScreen component

```
<template>
  <v-container class="result-container fill-height elevation-12">
    <v-container class="ma-0 pa-0">
      <v-row>
        <v-img class="img" :src="store.imgUrl" @click="downloadImg"></v-img>
      </v-row>
      <v-container v-if="store.progress === 100 && !isUpscaled" class="btn-container mt-3">
        <v-row class="justify-center" v-for="(row, index) in btnRows" :key="index">
          <v-col cols="auto" v-for="btn in row" :key="btn">
            <v-btn variant="tonal" @click="onClick(btn)">{{ btn }}</v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
      <v-row v-if="store.imgUrl && store.progress !== 100" class="justify-center mt-5">
        <v-progress-circular
          :rotate="360"
          :size="75"
          :width="15"
          :model-value="store.progress"
          color="teal"
          class=""
          align="center"
        >
          {{ store.progress }}
        </v-progress-circular>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-container>
</template>
```

I tried removing the fill-height class and defining a height of 100vh to the main container and then constraining all the child containers to max-height 100% but that also does not work and the content keeps overflowing. Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```css
box-sizing: border-box;
max-height: 100%;
max-width: 100%;
```

The border-box is there so that the size includes the padding as well, otherwise it will be the content is 100% and the padding is taking up the space. Also make sure your image doesn't have a fixed height or width either because it won't get smaller.

Also can we see your CSS because I don't know any Vuetify and I don't know what styles exactly are being applied. Or you can go in the DevTools, go to the "Elements" tab either look at the  element in the html or on the right there is a sidebar with tabs and a tab called "Styles" that shows you the styles for the element you clicked on.

Comment: Which styles would you like to see exactly? Vuetify is a component framework with properties and classes similar to bootstrap. There's literally hundreds of properties that are being applied to all the different elements in the UI. I would have to take over 10 screenshots to show you the styles applied to every element.